# Export gridview to csv

Tags: asp.net

I am trying export gridview to csv.

- I am adding actual record into cell of excel not trying html to excel.
- I am executing sp, taking record into datatable.
- Looping through datatable, writing into file using streamwriter.

But problem occur when my column has long number, csv shows 890+32 like this.

I don't want like this, want actual number like 89012345676898899998776766544333445556677.

How to do that? I am not using `Gridview.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter)`.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a code snippet of the streamwriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the number into a String and add a leading `'` to force excel to see the entry as text, like this:

`'89012345676898899998776766544333445556677`

Otherwise excel will see them as numbers (which they are, of course) and auto-format them in the unwanted format.

Comment: I made that number into string,but still facing problem.Is there is another way?Can I make excel sheet column to text before appending data

Comment: @JuiTest Try to add a `'` in front of the number, in addition to the String-casting.

Comment: Hi print x div 0,it worked as u told but my excel sheet column contain ''

Comment: @JuiTest, the leading or the trailing, or both? If you added the quotes "manually", then remove them accordingly. Otherwise I'm afraid I cannot help you. In any case I'll edit my answer to include the leading "'".